# Generic @BindingConversion doesn't work

Tags: android, generics, android-databinding

Why is it not possible to define generic binding conversion within android data binding library?

```
@BindingConversion
public static <T> T convertMyClass(MyClass<T> obj) {
    return obj.get();
}
```

With this method I am getting `can not find the setter for attribute 'android:text' with parameter type com.example.MyClass<java.lang.String>` error. Defining explicit types works alright.

I was trying to find the way `ObservableField<T>` is getting converted but didn't succeed. Does anyone know how is this happening? Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two words: [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

Generics are a double edged sword that cuts out some of the run time capability of the type system in exchange for compile time checks. You're telling the compiler to rewrite code to make these type conversions "just work." The trade-off is that it has to turn generic class references like "T" into just "Object". So the signature of your method after compilation is

```
Object convertMyClass(MyClass)
```

The data binding system is looking for a return type "String". And so doesn't even consider your method.

The data binding system could probably be made smarter, to be able to recognize your BindingConversion, but I wouldn't hold my breath for that feature.

Here is some bash which illustrates type erasure.

```
$ echo 'public class A{ public <T> T deRef(java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference<T> atom) {return atom.get();} }' >A.java
$ javac A.java
$ groovy -e 'println A.class.getMethod("deRef", java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference.class)'
public java.lang.Object A.deRef(java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference)
```

That last line of output is the method signature for the generic method.

A work-around would be to subclass MyClass with specific parameterized subclasses like so:

```
public class MyStringClass extends MyClass<String> {
  @Override
  public String get() {
    return super.get();
  }
  @BindingConversion
  public static String convertMyClass(MyStringClass obj) {
    return obj.get();
  }
}
```

Regarding [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField.html), it doesn't need the BindingConversion mechanism because the data-binding library references it in the java code, and therefore compile-time generics checking does the job of matching types up.

Comment: Do you think about any workaround to make this work?

Comment: @Bolein95 I updated it with a work-around. Does that work for you?

Comment: it doesn't. Genericism is lost. Anyway, your answer explains the problem. Seems like I have to report this to the data binding community.

Comment: Sorry I didn't address that part. If your java code references the type with generic parameters, you don't need to convert, because generics are providing that check. So data-binding references ObservableField, which means that when you use ObservableField<YourType>, compile time checking with generics ensures that the code will work, and the library doesn't need to introspect your classes for converters. I haven't actually looked through the data-binding source, but if you do, I guarantee the type variables in the data-binding source will simply work with your usage of ObservableField.